# Duplicating results from group_concat

Tags: sql, impala

Something is wrong with the group_concat(case() statements in this code. The resulting records are duplicating the dm name and salesrep name as long comma separated strings. How can I change this to get a single distinct result in each cell?

[current results example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwWue.png)

```
select

o.ro_number,
go.Rop_Product_Used_Fk,
go.Rop_Product_Billed_Fk,
go.Rop_Ar_Serial_Number_Fk,
o.Rop_Start_Bill_Timestamp,
o.Rop_Stop_Bill_Timestamp,
b.Customer_Billto_Name,
b.Customer_Billto_Account_Number,
b.Customer_Billto_Account_Site_id,
b.Customer_Billto_Site_Use_Id,
a.Corp_Par_Nm,
a.Ownr_Sub_Nm,
r.Requestor_Name,
r.Requestor_Account_Number,
--zt.Dm_name,
--zt.Salesrep_name,
--zt.Sales_credit_type_code,
group_concat(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN dm_name END, ',') AS 'Acute RSM',
group_concat(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN salesrep_name END,',') AS 'Acute Rep',
group_concat(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN dm_name END, ',') AS 'OOH RSM',
group_concat(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN salesrep_name END, ',') AS 'OOH Rep',
--t.Transition_Facility_Name,
--t.Transition_Facility_Account_Number,
--c.Caregiver_Account_Number,
--c.Caregiver_name_1,
p.Payor_group_name,
p.Payor_subgroup_name,
p.Payor_cat_code,
p.Payor_rpt_grp,
go.Rop_price,
--go.Rop_ra_price_list,
--go.rop_rtm_enabled,
case when o.Rop_Stop_Bill_Timestamp is null then datediff(now(),o.Rop_Start_Bill_Timestamp)+1 
when o.Rop_Stop_Bill_Timestamp is not null then datediff(o.Rop_Stop_Bill_Timestamp,o.Rop_Start_Bill_Timestamp)+1 else null end as 'Therapy Days',
count(distinct o.ro_number) as 'Placements'

from aim.aim_orders_dim o
left join aim.aim_orders_fact of on o.order_key = of.order_key
left join aim.aim_customer_zipterr_xref_transposed_vw zt on zt.customer_key = of.requestor_key
left join aim.aim_customer_billto_dim b on b.customer_billto_key = of.customer_billto_key
left join aim.aim_requestor_dim r on r.requestor_key = of.requestor_key
left join aim.aim_transition_facility_dim t on t.transition_facility_key = of.transition_facility_key
--left join aim.aim_caregiver_dim c on c.caregiver_key = of.caregiver_key
left join aim.aim_payor_dim p on p.payor_key = of.ro_payor_key
left join aim.aim_product_dim pr on pr.product_key = of.product_key
left join sand_cast.account_attributes a on a.customer_shipto_key = r.requestor_key
left join hero.genesis_rental_order_product go on go.rop_ro_fk = o.ro_number

where o.rop_system_status not in ('Cancelled', 'Pending')
and o.rop_status not in ('Cancelled', 'Pending')
--and o.rop_start_bill_timestamp <= '2020-12-31'
and (year(o.rop_stop_bill_timestamp) >= 2018 or o.rop_stop_bill_timestamp is null)
and go.rop_product_used_fk in ('WNDACT', 'WNDARM')
and pr.Rentalsale_flag = 'R'
and p.payor_rpt_grp = 'FSS'
and p.payor_group_name = 'VA MEDICAL'
and zt.sales_credit_type_code in ('ATR','AWT')

group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,19,20,21,22,23,24
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `distinct`:

```
group_concat(distinct CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN dm_name END, ',') AS 'Acute RSM',
group_concat(distinct CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN salesrep_name END,',') AS 'Acute Rep',
group_concat(distinct CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN dm_name END, ',') AS 'OOH RSM',
group_concat(distinct CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN salesrep_name END, ',') AS 'OOH Rep',
```

Comment: Tried that @Gordon Linoff, but getting this error:

AnalysisException: all DISTINCT aggregate functions need to have the same set of parameters as group_concat(DISTINCT CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN dm_name END, ','); deviating function: group_concat(DISTINCT CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN salesrep_name END, ',') Consider using NDV() instead of COUNT(DISTINCT) if estimated counts are acceptable. Enable the APPX_COUNT_DISTINCT query option to perform this rewrite automatically.